# How to track down memory leak not showing in visualvm

Tags: java, java-8, memory-leaks

Our code's memory usage is going up constantly, according to top, but when I look into visualvm it shows heap and metaspace are not growing and are GC correctly, so top and visualvm disagree on memory usage, and by a number way too large to be caused by mere overhead.

We are loading a number of 'tiles' into memory, it's no doubt something to do with failing to close resources used to either read or store them that's our root issue.  The problem is that It looks like were handling them correctly, I'm not seeing a failure to close or clean up and there is enough complexity in the code I'm not sure which moving piece to focus on.

I've run findbugs (yes findbugs, because my company expects me to move mountains to be able to download spotbugs to their infrastructure, why should we use up to date code when programming?).  It found plenty of bugs, but none of them were OS_OPEN_STREAM.  So findbugs apparently believes were closing things correctly.  Though considering how old it is I'm not sure it knows how to parse newer java 8 syntax we use regularly so perhaps I shouldn't trust that to mean much.  Still working on getting proper spotbugs internally.

What other tools might I be able to use to get a better idea of which classes are failing to clean up?

edit:

after some experimentation I can see the memory leak is in shared memory and according to pmap is looks like it's caused by a huge number of 300K nfs allocations.  Not sure if that tells me anything I didn't already know though.

Comment: Is numbers you see in `visualvm` consistent with numbers shown in `top`?

Comment: @talex no, top is reporting vastly more memory used then top is, as in like 20 gigs more, more then can be explained by the usual overhead